# ng new project not working stuck at "CREATE project/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)"

Tags: angular, npm

I built angular projects like this until yesterday, now it get stuck with no error

This is my terminal when it get stuck:

```
C:\Users\Fata189\Desktop>ng new project
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE project/angular.json (2705 bytes)
CREATE project/package.json (1038 bytes)
CREATE project/README.md (1061 bytes)
CREATE project/tsconfig.json (901 bytes)
CREATE project/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE project/.gitignore (548 bytes)
CREATE project/tsconfig.app.json (263 bytes)
CREATE project/tsconfig.spec.json (273 bytes)
CREATE project/.vscode/extensions.json (130 bytes)
CREATE project/.vscode/launch.json (474 bytes)
CREATE project/.vscode/tasks.json (938 bytes)
CREATE project/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE project/src/index.html (293 bytes)
CREATE project/src/main.ts (214 bytes)
CREATE project/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE project/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE project/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE project/src/app/app.component.html (23083 bytes)
CREATE project/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (959 bytes)
CREATE project/src/app/app.component.ts (211 bytes)
CREATE project/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
| Installing packages (npm)...
```

This is my Angular version:

```
C:\Users\Fata189\Desktop>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1500.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.0.4 (cli-only)
```

This is my npm version:

```
C:\Users\Fata189\Desktop>npm version
{
  npm: '9.2.0',
  node: '18.12.1',
  v8: '10.2.154.15-node.12',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '108',
  nghttp2: '1.47.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.10',
  openssl: '3.0.7+quic',
  cldr: '41.0',
  icu: '71.1',
  tz: '2022b',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0'
}
```

Node version: v18.12.1

This is my first Stack Overflow question so be kind please! If you need any other info ask me, thank you in advance!

I tried to install latest version of ng and npm and even uninstall and reinstall angular/cli, I tried to create it with different names and in different folders, one time it got stuck even earlier but all the other times it always got stuck at app.component.css

Comment: Sometimes this may happen due to internet speed. What is your internet speed?

Comment: Great first question!

Comment: @aghwotu doing the speedtest by Ookla I have 107mbps in download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aghwotu said it's a internet connection problem, it's just a bit slow!